# Manifest merger failed, after setup android-gms:play-services-ads couldn't combine with appcompat issue

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

> I upgraded Android studio and then I tried to adapt for my project to Admob but I have this error:
>   [image]
>   My build config compile sdk version like this;

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "samples.hasan.deneme.com"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
[image]

Comment: Add this in your application tag in Manifest file:

tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"

Comment: between which tags will be written? @ErselanKhan

Comment: Application tag where you define your application name, icon, theme etc

Comment: @ErselanKhan Error changed; 

:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 51s